# How to lookup obscure windows message codes?

Tags: mfc, winapi

I'm receiving a windows message with code 1092 (0x444) and I don't know what it is. It's higher than WM_USER but I searched our code base and found no reference so I don't think it's one of ours... does Windows use custom messages above 0x400 and if so how can I look this up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentanion of [WM_USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644931%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Message numbers in the second range
>   (WM_USER through 0x7FFF) can be
>   defined and used by an application to
>   send messages within a private window
>   class. These values cannot be used to
>   define messages that are meaningful
>   throughout an application, because
>   some predefined window classes already
>   define values in this range. **For
>   example, predefined control classes
>   such as BUTTON, EDIT, LISTBOX, and
>   COMBOBOX may use these values.**
>   Messages in this range should not be
>   sent to other applications unless the
>   applications have been designed to
>   exchange messages and to attach the
>   same meaning to the message numbers.

So, that message can be *anything*.
A quick look in the MFC source code, for example, reveals these definitions

```
// COMMCTRL.H
#define TB_ADDBUTTONSW        (WM_USER + 68)

// RICHEDIT.H
#define EM_SETCHARFORMAT      (WM_USER + 68)
```

I searched for `68` because `0x444 = 0x400 + 0x44 = WM_USER + 68`

Comment: EM_SETCHARFORMAT. It must be this one, as I call SetFont just before it is seen. Thanks a lot, also good post more generally.

Answer (score 1):

Any application can use messages above WM_USER or WM_APP. Windows itself even uses messages above WM_USER. Because any application can broadcast these message values (and some do, because they're written by idiots), you should always use registered messages for private comms.

You could use Spy++ to try and track these messages down, but you can't guarantee ever stopping them all, so it's best to avoid them by using RegisterWindowMessage.

Answer (score 0):

You could search around in the Windows headers for strings like `0x444`, `0x0444`, `0x00000444`, etc.

It might also be a rogue application sending around messages that it shouldn't.